# Put a java socket-like program in a cloud service

Tags: java, sockets, cloud, firewall

I developed a server side java program, basically is a relay server so I can easily pass NATs and firewalls. The program works, but now I need a cloud service to host it. Do you know where/how I can put a java socket-like program in the cloud?

Obviously, I prefer a free service or at least a free service while I'm testing.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think anyone is going to give you hosting/bandwidth for free. If you find someone that will, let me know. :)

A host for testing should be simple enough if your traffic volume is small: just setup up a box somewhere and open a port to the outside world for you to use.

For production, there's always [Amazon EC2](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/), although they're a bit expensive for my tasted when it comes to bandwidth. I've heard good things about [linode](http://www.linode.com/) and if you're willing to cough up enough money, I'm sure some hosting service will give you as much bandwidth as you desire.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to create Java sockets with Google.

Answer (score 0):

[dev@cloud](http://www.cloudbees.com/dev.cb) (formerly Stax) offers some free app hosting, while Amazon's micro EC2 instances are free for the first 12 months with a new AWS account.

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at the FREE GOOGLE APPS for personal use.
All you have to do is to point a domain of your own to their Apps and enable "Google App Engine"

Here is to get you started with Google Apps hosting:
http://www.google.com/apps/intl/en/group/index.html

You'll get free e-mail hosting (GMAIL interface), free Google Docs and free Google Calendar as a bonus. Once you have registrated and pointed your domain to Google Apps Dashboard, then you can enable the App Engine.

You'll find more info here:
http://code.google.com/intl/us-en/appengine/

Please let me know if this works for you, as we dont use JAVA at my company, but only .NET

Hope this was the answer you were looking for and that you will mark it as such :o)